# Is there any bash script to find the difference of two directories and copy the difference to next third directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Actually I need a script that compare the content of two directories and copy the difference to next directory. Suppose I have dir1 which contains file1 and file2; dir2 which contains file1 then the script should calculate dir1-dir2 and copy the difference i.e. only file2 to next directory suppose let's say dir3.

Comment: There are probably better ways to achieve what you want. Maybe explain why you would want this, and better options may emerge.